# How do I use omnifaces coalesce to turn nulls into a number, for use in ChoiceFormat

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I currently have the following JSF:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{msg['label.address.province']}" 
               rendered="#{address.country ne CountryEnum.UNITED_STATES.country}"/>
<p:outputLabel value="#{msg['label.address.province']}" 
               rendered="#{address.country eq CountryEnum.UNITED_STATES.country}"/>
```

And my properties file contains

```
label.address.province=Province
label.address.state=State
```

This works fine, and when the country is "US", my label outputs "State", and for any other country, it outputs "Province".

What I had thought to do, is try to get rid of the two label entries and just use one, with a choiceformat in the messages.properties. My first try looked like:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msg['label.address.province.choice']}">
    <f:param value="#{address.country.id}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

with

```
label.address.province.choice={0, choice, 1#Province|2#State|3#Province}
```

Which worked fine, when editing an address. But when adding a new address, by my business rules, all fields are blank. Which means address.country is null, which means my choiceformat produces 'null' as output.

Then I thought to use omnifaces:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msg['label.address.province.choice']}">
    <f:param value="#{o.coalesce(address.country.id, '1')}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

But this also produces null. address is my managed bean, country is my own simple javabean class, id is a property of type `java.io.Serializable`.

I know that "address.country.id" is evaluated by EL and it "nicely" stops when it encounters null and doesn't throw an NPE.  But, is it perhaps that coalesce doesn't do this same type of behaviour, and what I pass in must be a non-EL expression? Sorry, I'm just beginning my JSF adventure so I'm probably not using the right words.

I'm also open to just taking a totally different approach, which still reduces my outputLabels to a single label of some type.

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.21, Primefaces 3.5, Omnifaces 1.4.1, Java 7, Tomcat 7

Comment: I'm afraid your problem is just a simple typo. It's `#{of:coalesce(...)}`, not `#{o.coalesce(...)}` whereby `of` namespace is declared as `xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"`. Note the colon instead of period when using EL functions. See also http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Objects

Comment: Oh drat, what a stupid mistake :/.  Actually, I had it declared in my namespace as xmlns:o, and on the same page (to be able to use the Enums) I've already got `<o:importConstants type="com...domain.CountryEnum" />` and it works.  But, change it to "of", just to be sure, and using a colon, I now get: 

javax.el.ELException: Function 'of:coalesce' not found

Comment: oh.  duh.  two namespaces, one is o, the other is of.  Got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here,

```
<f:param value="#{o.coalesce(address.country.id, '1')}"/>
```

there are two (actually, three) mistakes:

1. The namespace is likely not correct, it's at least not the default one of OmniFaces EL functions. From the [OmniFaces homepage](http://omnifaces.org):

   > The OmniFaces UI components/taghandlers and EL functions are available under the following XML namespaces:
   >
   > ```
   > xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
   > xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
   > ```
2. The EL function operator is `:`, not `.`. EL functions have the syntax of `namespace:functionname(...)`.
3. The third mistake, which is not related to the concrete problem, is that you're specifying a string instead of a number as value. The `#{'1'}` should have been `#{1}`.

So, all with all, you should have

```
<f:param value="#{of:coalesce(address.country.id, 1)}"/>
```

Your concrete problem was caused because the `#{o}` does likely not exist as a variable (e.g. a managed bean) anywhere in the EL scope and evaluates thus as `null`.

Comment: Thanks.  The last bit is that '1' should just be plain 1.  Otherwise it's a `Cannot format given Object as a Number` exception.